# Very new to slurm. How to get slurm to run multiple core jobs on my linux cluster?

Tags: linux, slurm, mpi

I've been trying to move some existing processes to a revamped linux cluster that now runs on slurm.   I thought I have it done, but my problem now is trying to get multiple cores to run.

Here is my submission script.

```
   #!/bin/bash
   #
   #SBATCH --job-name=test_mpi
   #SBATCH --output=res_mpi.txt
   #
   #SBATCH -n 4
   #SBATCH --time=10:00
   srun mkdir -p /tmp/tedhyu/new
  srun cp Ru13.in /tmp/tedhyu/new/lcao.in
  srun cp ~tedhyu/atom_pbe/* /tmp/tedhyu/new
  srun cd /tmp/tedhyu/new
  srun -N 1  -n 4 --chdir=/tmp/tedhyu/new  mpiexec ~tedhyu/bin/origin1_centos6.4_mpich2_quest_265c.x
```

When I "qstat -n" it only shows one core:

Job id               Username Queue    Name                 SessID NDS   TSK   Memory Time Use S Time

---

11778                tedhyu   atom     test_mpi             --         1     4     -- 00:10 C 00:00
node3-5/4

Here is the first few lines of my output that shows only 1 core is running:

```
    srun: error: node3-5: tasks 0-3: Exited with exit code 1
     MPINFO::: Global Communicator        :::
     MPINFO::: Global Context = ****      :::
     MPINFO::: Global Size =       1      :::
     MPINFO::: Global Root =       0      :::
     MPINFO::: Global Rank =       0      :::
     DEV: VDW development version
```

Global Size should equal 4

If anyone can point me in the right direction...  Thanks!!!

Comment: thanks.  Sorry, just starting out on this.

Answer (score 0):

do not use srun in the last line of the script. Just launch the executable there with mpirun or mpiexec.

what srun does : it is launches $SLURM_NTASKS instances ( one per reserved CPU core) of the command which comes after it. You don't want that, you want mpiexec to spawn the tasks to the CPUs. E.g. your last line can be

mpirun -np $SLURM_NTASKS ./myexecutable.exe